# Оптимизация кода. Условия if ... else:

Tags: python, оптимизация, if

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать данные условия, чтобы код выглядел компактнее и не так убого.
Вот сам код: ИСПРАВЛЕННЫЙ ВАРИАНТ!

```
if not sums1.values():
    m1 = (0,0)
else: 
    m1 = max(sums1.items())
if not sums2.values():
    m2 = (0,0)
else:
    m2 = max(sums2.items())
if not sums3.values():
    m3 = (0,0)
else:
    m3 = max(sums3.items()) 
if not sums4.values():
    m4 = (0,0)
else:
    m4 = max(sums4.items())
if not sums5.values():
    m5 = (0,0)
else:
    m5 = max(sums5.items()) 
if not sums6.values():
    m6 = (0,0)
else:
    m6 = max(sums6.items())
```

Пример:

max(sums1.items()) = (132.4, 5.66)

Где 132.4 - это номер максимальной цены, а 5.66 это максимальная цена.

sums1.items() = ([(19151.0, 0.0379), (19150.0, 0.0001), (19148.0,
3.1432000000000007), (19146.0, 0.24550000000000002), (19141.0, 0.0528)])

Comment: и как вы с этим кодом собираетесь работать дальше? часть переменных будет не инициализирована

Comment: Да, у меня выходила ошибка с проблемами по нахождению переменных, когда условие отрабатывало вариант с pass ). Думал проблема в другом, а потом осенило ) Извиняюсь, что я всех вас ввёл в заблуждение.  Я в программировании не давно, около двух месяцев и бывает так, что сильно торможу ). Я сейчас исправил код, вот его нужно сократить. Спасибо всем за ответы, и ещё раз извиняюсь за не корректный пример.

Comment: а ничего что по одной ветке переменная получит число, равное максимуму, а по второй кортеж ?

Comment: `sums1.items() = ([(19151.0, 0.0379), (19150.0, 0.0001), (19148.0, 3.1432000000000007), (19146.0, 0.24550000000000002), (19141.0, 0.0528)])` присмотритесь внимательно к этому выражению. Если Вы имели в виду операцию присвоения (то-есть сделать `items()` равной правой части выражения), то это так не работает, если же Вы имели в виду сравнение, то это пишется через `==`

Answer (score 4):

Да простая инверсия условия уже сокращает код в два раза

```
if sums1.values():
    m1 = max(sums1.items())
```

И не надо никаких `else` и `pass`. Если в ветке `if` стоит только `pass`, то очевидно, что тут надо наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Извините за не корректный пример кода, я его исправил, если есть желание сделать ещё один пример с исправленным вариантом, то буду очень благодарен )

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя не создавать m-переменные, если sums пуcтые, т.к. потом будет неочевидно, можно ли ее использовать или она не определена, проще все в dict или list сохранить, которые запомнят соответствие m и sums, но если очень хочется делать именно так, то:

```
for e, s in enumerate((sums1, sums2, sums3, sums4, ), start=1):
    if s:
        locals()[f'm{e}'] = max(s.values())
print(m2)  # 3
```

--

```
M = {e: max(s.values() or [0]) for e, s in enumerate([sums1, sums2, sums3, sums4, ], start=1)}
print(M[2])  # 3

locals().update({f'm{e}': m for e, m in M.items()})
print(m2)  # 3
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Извините за не корректный пример кода, я его исправил, если есть желание сделать ещё один пример с исправленным вариантом, то буду очень благодарен )

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать генератор

```
m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6 = (max(x.items()) if x.values() else None for x in [sums1, sums2, sums3, sums4, sums5, sums6])
```

но нужно всегда возвращать какое-то значение, чтобы понимать, в какую переменную что попадет, да и просто, чтобы длины кортежей совпали

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Извините за не корректный пример кода, я его исправил, если есть желание сделать ещё один пример с исправленным вариантом, то буду очень благодарен )

Answer (score 1):

если есть старое значение `m1`, которое должно сохраняться при условии, то

```
if not sums1.values():
    pass
else: 
    m1 = max(sums1.items())
```

можно преобразовать в

```
m1 = max(sums1.items()) if sums1.values() else m1
```

для остальных записей аналогично

По идее вообще все можно свернуть в такое:

```
arr = [(m1, sums1), (m2, sums2), (m3, sums3), (m4, sums4), (m5, sums5), (m6, sums6)]
m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6 = [max(sums.items()) if sums.values() else m for m, sums in arr]
```

Answer (score 1):

вы не указали какой тип данных у sums1, sums2 и т.д., но есть подозрение, что это словари. если это действительно так, то можно обойтись без проверки условий, примерно так:

```
m1 = max(sums1.items(), default=None)
m2 = max(sums2.items(), default=None)
# и т.д.
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def get_max(elem: dict):
    # Поскольку словарь не имеющий значений не будет иметь и ключей
    # То вполне себе можно ограничиться проверкой самого словаря
    if elem:
        # поскольку dict.items() это кортеж кортежей
        # возникает вопрос, а по каким критериям
        # определяется максимальный из кортежей
        # возьму на себя смелость предположить,
        # что по второму элементу кортежа
        return max(elem.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

# Можно что-то такое замудрить, но по-хорошему нужно разбираться там, 
# где вы наделали такую кучу словарей 
m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6 = map(get_max, [sums1, sums2, sums3, sums4, sums5, sums6])
```

---

##### UPD

*В вопросе принципиально ничего, кроме того, что Вы добавили дефолтное значение, не поменялось*

```py
sums1 = dict([(19151.0, 0.0379), (19150.0, 0.0001), (19148.0, 3.1432000000000007), (19146.0, 0.24550000000000002), (19141.0, 0.0528)])
sums2 = dict()
sums3 = dict([(29151.0, 2.0379), (29150.0, 4.0001), (29148.0, 2.1432000000000007), (29146.0, 1.24550000000000002), (29141.0, 1.0528)])

d_max = lambda x: max(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], default=(0, 0))

print(
    d_max(sums1),
    d_max(sums2),
    d_max(sums3),
    sep='\n'
)
#  (19148.0, 3.1432000000000007)
#  (0, 0)
#  (29150.0, 4.0001)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Извините за не корректный пример кода, я его исправил, если есть желание сделать ещё один пример с исправленным вариантом, то буду очень благодарен )

Comment: @КириллМаколов, скажите, а код, в котором получаются эти 6 словарей (надеюсь что это все-таки словари) Вы сами писали? Обновил ответ, надеюсь он Вам поможет.

Comment: _'по каким критериям определяется максимальный из кортежей возьму на себя смелость предположить, что по второму элементу кортежа'_ не совсем так. `max({1000:20,100:1000}.items())` -> (1000, 20)